# Facebook App, Wrong access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm using the Graph Explorer, and I'm choosing my application from the Application Drop Down List.

I'm having to access this photo https://graph.facebook.com/399744030064153.

When i choose the application, facebook automatically the access token for the app and I'm being able to view the photo details.

However, in my php application, when i do

```
$access_token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
$photoObj=$facebook->api("https://graph.facebook.com/399744030064153?access_token=$access_token");
```

Its not working, from what i know, the access token is wrong because I'm trying to echo the access token and I check it. Thus, the problem is the access token

Does someone has an idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graph API explorer automatically generates a user access token, which gives the app the ability to act on a user's behalf. - in this case, your own account.

The getAccessToken() method in the SDK, if used standalone (i.e not as part of the [documented Auth flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)) will return an App Access Token, which although usable with the API won't be able to view any content unless it's Publicly visible

Comment: what do you mean "Publicly visible"? where do i check this?

Comment: If it comes back via the API on a request without a user access token, it's publicly visible